# What is the relationship between an open set and its closure in a topological space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the relationship between an open set and its closure in a topological space?

We know closure of a closed set and the set are the same. I am wondering if we have a general statement if the set is open

.

Comment: The best you can say in general is that the closure of an open set contains the open set. It may be equal to it (for example, the closure of $\varnothing$ is itself; or more generally, the closure of any union of connected components of the space), or it may properly contain it.

Comment: $A^{\circ} \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}$.

Comment: You can't even say that the interior of the closure is the original set, even if the original set is an open set (consider a slit disk).

Comment: Closures of open sets are called "regular closed sets" and crop up in some topology contexts; they form a compleet Boolean algebra among other things, and are useful in studying $H$-closed spaces. The operation $A \to \overline{(A^\circ)}$ on $A$, when done twice yields the same result as done only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closures and closedness get along well, as do interiors and openness:

- We have $\overline{A}\supseteq A$ for *all* sets $A$, but $\overline{A}=A$ **if and only if** $A$ is closed.
- Similarly, $A^\circ\subseteq A$ for *all* sets $A$, but $A^\circ=A$ **if and only if** $A$ is open.

But there isn't really anything special about open sets as far as closures are concerned. The only nontrivial thing we can say really is that $A$ is open if and only if we have $\overline{A^c}=A^c$ (where $^c$ denotes the complement), but that's just recapitulating the characterization of closed sets together with the fact that "open = complement is closed." And the situation is the same for interiors and closed sets.

Comment: I was trying to solve the following qestion